# jQuery Invalid Argument 5899 in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

I tried using the [Moving Boxes](http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/) jQuery Plugin in Asp.net Mvc.  It works in every browser except for IE.
Heres the plug in code. I was wondering if somebody has an idea on what might be different in IE, possibly something along the lines of the way IE parses widths? or fixed widths?

```
$(function () {

var totalPanels = $(".scrollContainer").children().size();

var regWidth = $(".panel").css("width");
var regImgWidth = $(".panel img").css("width");
var regTitleSize = $(".panel h2").css("font-size");
var regParSize = $(".panel p").css("font-size");

var movingDistance = 200;

var curWidth = 300;
var curImgWidth = 250;
var curTitleSize = "15px";
var curParSize = "12px";

var $panels = $('#slider .scrollContainer > div');
var $container = $('#slider .scrollContainer');

$panels.css({ 'float': 'left', 'position': 'relative' });

$("#slider").data("currentlyMoving", false);

$container
    .css('width', ($panels[0].offsetWidth * $panels.length) + 135)
    .css('left', "-195px");

var scroll = $('#slider .scroll').css('overflow', 'hidden');

function returnToNormal(element) {
    $(element)
        .animate({ width: regWidth })
        .find("img")
        .animate({ width: regImgWidth })
        .end()
        .find("h2")
        .animate({ fontSize: regTitleSize })
        .end()
        .find("p")
        .animate({ fontSize: regParSize });
};

function growBigger(element) {
    $(element)
        .animate({ width: curWidth })
        .find("img")
        .animate({ width: curImgWidth })
        .end()
        .find("h2")
        .animate({ fontSize: curTitleSize })
        .end()
        .find("p")
        .animate({ fontSize: curParSize });
}

//direction true = right, false = left
function change(direction) {

    //if not at the first or last panel
    if ((direction && !(curPanel < totalPanels)) || (!direction && (curPanel <= 1))) { return false; }

    //if not currently moving
    if (($("#slider").data("currentlyMoving") == false)) {

        $("#slider").data("currentlyMoving", true);

        var next = direction ? curPanel + 1 : curPanel - 1;
        var leftValue = $(".scrollContainer").css("left");
        var movement = direction ? parseFloat(leftValue, 10) - movingDistance : parseFloat(leftValue, 10) + movingDistance;

        $(".scrollContainer")
            .stop()
            .animate({
                "left": movement
            }, function () {
                $("#slider").data("currentlyMoving", false);
            });

        returnToNormal("#panel_" + curPanel);
        growBigger("#panel_" + next);

        curPanel = next;

        //remove all previous bound functions
        $("#panel_" + (curPanel + 1)).unbind();

        //go forward
        $("#panel_" + (curPanel + 1)).click(function () { change(true); });

        //remove all previous bound functions                                                           
        $("#panel_" + (curPanel - 1)).unbind();

        //go back
        $("#panel_" + (curPanel - 1)).click(function () { change(false); });

        //remove all previous bound functions
        $("#panel_" + curPanel).unbind();
    }
}

// Set up "Current" panel and next and prev
growBigger("#panel_3");
var curPanel = 3;

$("#panel_" + (curPanel + 1)).click(function () { change(true); });
$("#panel_" + (curPanel - 1)).click(function () { change(false); });

//when the left/right arrows are clicked
$(".right").click(function () { change(true); });
$(".left").click(function () { change(false); });

$(window).keydown(function (event) {
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 13: //enter
            $(".right").click();
            break;
        case 32: //space
            $(".right").click();
            break;
        case 37: //left arrow
            $(".left").click();
            break;
        case 39: //right arrow
            $(".right").click();
            break;
    }
});
```

});

Comment: I thought the title was fairly specific but when it renders in an IE browser it throws an Invalid Argument 5899 in jQuery 1.4.2 I've ready through some docs and it seems like IE has issues with widths in jquery however I could not see where this would apply in this particular plug in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Justin - I don't have much of an answer for you, but if it seems to be centered around the `width` property, try using jQuery's `.width()` method to get the width.

So instead of:

```
var regWidth = $(".panel").css("width");
var regImgWidth = $(".panel img").css("width");
```

try:

```
var regWidth = $(".panel").width();
var regImgWidth = $(".panel img").width();
```

Maybe jQuery does some fixes. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up using something a little different but that definitely solves the IE bug.